# Elixir "case clause error" while pattern matching HTTPoison response

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, httpoison

I'm using Httpoison to perform a get request and I want to pattern match the response using a case statement. Here is the code:

```
  def current() do
    case HTTPoison.get!(@api_url) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body, status_code: 200}} ->
        IO.puts body
      {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
        IO.inspect reason
    end
  end
```

When the status code is 200, print the body.
When there is an error, inspect the reason.

I get response from the server like so,

```
%HTTPoison.Response{body: "{\"USD\":10067.08}", headers: <<removed for readability>>, status_code: 200}
```

And the error of,  **(CaseClauseError) no case clause matching:**

Why am I getting a "no clause" error when I'm getting a response with a body and status code of 200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is the `!` after `get`

`HTTPoison.get!(@api_url)` will return `%HTTPoison.Response{body: body, ...}` or raise exception.

If you want `{:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body, ...}` then use `HTTPoison.get(@api_url)` (without `!`) instead.

Either this:

```
def current() do
    case HTTPoison.get(@api_url) do
      {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body, status_code: 200}} ->
        IO.puts body
      {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
        IO.inspect reason
    end
end
```

OR

```
def current() do
    %HTTPoison.Response{body: body, status_code: 200}} = HTTPoison.get!(@api_url) 
    IO.puts body           
end
```